# What is the difference between FC and MLP in as used in PointNet?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, models, pytorch

I am trying to understand the [PointNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593) network for dealing with point clouds and struggling with understanding the difference between FC and MLP:

> "FC is fully connected layer operating on each point. MLP is
>   multi-layer perceptron on each point."

I understand how [fully connected](https://missinglink.ai/guides/convolutional-neural-networks/fully-connected-layers-convolutional-neural-networks-complete-guide/) layers are used to classify and I previously thought, was that MLP was the same thing but it seems varying academic papers have a differing definition from each other and from general online courses. In PointNet what is meant by a shared MLP different to a standard feedforward fully connected network?

[image: PointNet Network Architecture]

Answer (score 1):

An **MLP** is just a fully-connected feedforward neural net. In PointNet, a **shared MLP** means that you are applying the *exact same* MLP to each point in the point cloud.

Think of a CNN's convolutional layer. There you apply the exact same filter at all locations, and hence the filter weights are *shared* or *tied*. If they were not shared, you'd have potentially different filters (MLPs) at each pixel (point), updating independently.

As an example, let $f_\theta$ be an MLP with parameters $\theta$. Say we have a 3D point cloud $[\vec{x}_1,\ldots,\vec{x}_n]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$. If we apply $f_\theta$ as a shared MLP in the way PointNet describes, the result would be $[f_\theta(\vec{x}_1),\ldots,f_\theta(\vec{x}_n)]$.